# dbcp: number of open prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I get MaxOpenPreparedStatement exception in my program. I can monitor number of objects in GenericObjectPool with getNumActive()/getNumIdle() functions. How can I get connection & prepared statement pools from org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource object?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the answer on the *actual* question, but the maximum allowable amount of opened preparedstatements is usually pretty high. So I strongly suspect that the technical problem causing you to ask this question is that the JDBC code is not properly closing all the opened statements in the `finally` block as per the following JDBC idiom:

```
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
// ...

try {
    connection = database.getConnection();
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_STRING);
    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    // ...
} finally {
    if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    if (preparedStatement != null) try { preparedStatement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DBCP's BasicDataSource exposes the [maxOpenPreparedStatements](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#maxOpenPreparedStatements) value that the datasource is configured with.

The presence of this exception seems to indicate that you are opening too many statements and not closing them however:

> Since a connection usually only uses one or two statements at a time, this is mostly used to help detect resource leaks.

Comment: It is a configuration value, not current statictics

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get a hold of the DBCP internals by subclassing BasicDataSource, then overriding createPoolableConnectionFactory and replacing the statement pool factory with one you create yourself (and thus are able to track).

As with the other answers here, this would seem to indicate prepared statements are being left open - in which case you'll have the same problem even if you turn prepared statement pooling off (or stop using a connection pool at all), which might make the original problem a lot easier to debug.